# MYSQL replace part of table

Tags: mysql

I have the following data that grows too large too quickly:

```
c1    c2       timestamp
5      1       2019-01-31 15:35:36.055000
6      2       2019-01-31 15:35:36.055000
7      3       2019-01-31 15:35:35.055000
8      4       2019-01-31 15:35:35.055000
7      3       2019-01-30 15:35:36.055000
8      4       2019-01-30 15:35:36.055000
7      3       2019-01-30 15:35:35.055000
8      4       2019-01-30 15:35:35.055000
```

I want to replace part of the table by ceiling the timestamps to 10 second intervals where timestamp is older than 2019-01-31 00:00:00:000000
The result should be this and the bottom two columns from the aforementioned table should NOT be in the new table:

```
c1    c2       timestamp
5      1       2019-01-31 15:35:36.055000
6      2       2019-01-31 15:35:36.055000
7      3       2019-01-31 15:35:35.055000
8      4       2019-01-31 15:35:35.055000
7      3       2019-01-30 15:35:40.000000
8      4       2019-01-30 15:35:40.000000
```

I did the following query to ceil the timestamp, but I dont know how to replace that certain part of the table.

```
SELECT c1, c2, FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 10) * 10) as datetime 
FROM mytable
WHERE timestamp in (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM mytable
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 10) * 10)) 
GROUP BY datetime
```

Comment: Do you need the values actually rounded, or are you just trying to have only one for every 10 second interval for each c1, c2 pairing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Note: If c1 or c2 can be null, this solution will probably not work for you without significant modification.)*

If you just want to keep the most recent from each 10 second window, something like this should work:

```
DELETE 
FROM mytable
WHERE timestamp < '2019-01-31 00:00:00:000000'
    AND (c1, c2, timestamp) 
        NOT IN (
           SELECT ends.c1, ends.c2, ends.windowEnd
           FROM (  SELECT c1, c2
                      , FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 10) * 10) as dtWindow
                      , MAX(timestamp) AS windowEnd
                   FROM mytable
                   WHERE timestamp < '2019-01-31 00:00:00:000000'
                   GROUP BY c1, c2, dtWindow
                ) AS ends
        )
;
```

Note: sometimes MySQL is a little bit finicky about selecting from the table you are deleting from in the same query, but I think there are enough levels of indirection in that subquery that it should not be an issue.

---

Bonus: If you want to double check the records that will be deleted before running such a query, you can move the subselect into a joining select to preview things.

```
SELECT t.*
, CASE WHEN ends.rowPresent IS NOT NULL THEN 'keep' ELSE 'to delete' END AS `plan`
FROM mytable AS t 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT c1, c2
      , FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 10) * 10) as dtWindow
      , MAX(timestamp) AS windowEnd
      , 1 AS rowPresent -- You could just use c1 or c2 in the above CASE, but if they could naturally be null that would complicate things
   FROM mytable
   WHERE timestamp < '2019-01-31 00:00:00:000000'
   GROUP BY c1, c2, dtWindow
) AS ends ON t.c1 = ends.c1 AND t.c2 = ends.c2 AND t.timestamp = ends.windowEnd
WHERE t.timestamp < '2019-01-31 00:00:00:000000'
;
```

Comment: looks good, but I get the Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: oops, fixed now, added the alias where it was needed

Answer (score 1):

A query like this will ceil the timestamp value for all rows

```
UPDATE mytable SET timestamp=FROM_UNIXTIME(CEIL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 10) * 10);
```

Add a WHERE clause if you want to apply it to only some rows